# Specify camel context shutdown order with multiple contexts

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a Camel / Spring application with multiple contexts (say 3 - A, B & C). The contexts are designed to be started / stopped in a specific order. Startup: C, B, then A. Shutdown A, B, then C. There is a lot of documentation about specifying shutdown order in a single Camel context but I don't find anything about it were the routes are in multiple contexts. The `DefaultShutdownStrategy` only seems to support one context.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches to explore:

1. Use bundle run-levels in a Karaf-based container to ensure shutdown is reverse of startup
2. Design a convention where you can leverage the Camel controlbus and have one "master" route in charge of startup and shutdown. Configure all routes to *not* startup automatically, except for the one "master" route. That route then starts and stops routes in what ever order is needed.
3. You mentioned Spring.. I'm surprised it is not honoring the startup order in reverse on shutdown. Generally, Blueprint does a good job reversing startup order.